# SNES development: why bitplanes get scrambled?

Tags: sprites, nintendo, assembly

I am following this tutorial https://georgjz.github.io/snesaa04/. I am stuck on trying to draw a sprite.

Where the end result should be this:

[image]

My end result is this:

[image]

As I have not been able to find samples of tile and palette files, I am not sure if I have done everything right.

Sprites.vra:

```
0b 2e 2a 3f 1e 1f 0f 3f 2e 3f 1c 1f 0c ff f3 fe
2f 00 3f 00 1f 00 3c 00 38 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
```

SpriteColors.pal:

```
fe 3f 3e 77 f8 5d 0f 49 ff 7f f8 6f 8a 6b 49 62
64 39 e0 2c 60 18 98 04 9f 0e 3e 09 2c 00 00 00
```

As the tutorial proposes, I use cc65 as a compiler. The files are included like this:

```
.segment "SPRITEDATA"
SpriteData: .incbin "Sprites.vra"
ColorData:  .incbin "SpriteColors.pal"
```

As I could not get bsnes working, I am using Snes9X.

As this failed, I tried to draw a plane with just one color as well to figure out the logic. I did not manage, as the colors were always scrambled.

**Questions:**

How should the tile/bitplane and palette files look like?
What is the checksum error my emulator throws?

As a last note: please be patient if this is basic stuff. I am ex web dev and a retro game hobbyist, and assembly code is completely foreign world to me.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Just to clarify - where did you get the sprite & palette data from? I didn't see those resources in the tutorial, but maybe I just missed them. If they're not from the tutorial, we may need more details about how you got the sprite related information.

Comment: @Pikalek Ah sorry for the confusion. They were based on instructions given in lesson 3 of the tutorial: https://georgjz.github.io/snesaa03/

Comment: No worries, just trying to eliminate possible sources of error. Related to that, are you sure the sprite files are encoded as hex/binary & not ASCIII/text? I made that mistake myself once or twice with assembly :P

Comment: @Pikalek it seems that was it! Thank you very much! If you like, write an answer out of it so I can accept and give you the points.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I've posted an answer that included the thought process that led me to that suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When coding in assembly, it can be easy to mix up your data format. In this particular case, the assembly code is expecting the `.pal` and `.vra` files to be in hex / binary. For instance, here's the `.pal` data from the [tutorial](https://georgjz.github.io/snesaa03/):

[image: hex code for .pal file]

The far left columns indicate the memory offset, the middle column is the data in hexadecimal form & the far right column is the data in ASCII.

So, if properly encoded, if you open the `.pal` file in something like Notepad, you should see the data as presented on the right, starting with  `?>w ] I   o kIbd`.

If, instead you see `fe3f3e77f8` and so forth in a text editor, then the data has been encoded as text / ASCII and will not represent what you want or what the assembly program is expecting.

My first clue that this was a data representation problem was the combination that the data came directly from the tutorial & the error returned was complaining about a bad checksum. Unless the tutorial itself was flawed, this suggested that somewhere, bad / unexpected data was getting processed. I've made similar errors myself when dealing with assembly & hex data.

Using a good hex editing tool will help, but it's still possible to make mistakes, so if you are experiencing data problems, it's a good idea to double check your data format & encoding.